# How to override a view that have includes in smarty / prestashop?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have to override a module view in my custom theme. I copied the tpl I want to override in the right directory but it contains lots of `{include file="./[filename].tpl" }` and smarty fails with `Smarty: Unable to load template`. This seems fair, since the files it wants to include are not in my theme override.

Copy dozens of file for a single line cosmetic override seems way too dirty to me.

Is there a way so that I can override a single tpl without have to copy all included files in my theme?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the paths of the include to where the files actually are:

```
{include file="$module_dir.[tpl_dir]/[filename].tpl"}
```

Comment: Tried that. But `$modules_dir` is /modules/ (with initial slash) and the include is searching in the server root and not in /var/www/.